# Animate R specific geoms in ggplot/gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, gganimate, geom

I have a dataset where I want to create an animated plot. This plot is going to show progression of the x and y values over time. I can get that working just fine, where this produces a plot with a moving point:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(gifski)
library(transformr)

main_data <- data.frame(timestep=as.POSIXct(1L:10L, origin=Sys.time()),
                        x=1L:10L, y=1L:10L)

main_data %>% 
  ggplot(data=main_data, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, group=1)) +
    geom_point() + 
    transition_manual(timestep) ->
    plot_1

animate(plot_1, duration=5, fps=2, renderer=gifski_renderer())
```

However, **what I'd like to add is a `geom_path()` showing the path of the data in the background and that should be static, so it is present in every frame of the animation and the point moves along it**. Is there a way to do this? I have experimented with a few things and thought maybe adding it "after" the transition might work, but no luck.

```
plot_1 + 
  geom_path() ->
  plot_2

animate(plot_2, duration=5, fps=2, renderer=gifski_renderer())
```

---

---

---

A similar effect is created using the `geom_hline()` which acts as a static element in the figure:

```
plot_1 +
  geom_hline(yintercept=4) -> 
  plot_3

animate(plot_3, duration=5, fps=2, renderer=gifski_renderer())
```

And a similar effect is created by using `geom_abline()` but the actual data I will use this for will follow a non-linear path so that won't work (but at least it shows what I am trying to achieve).

```
plot_1 + 
  geom_abline() -> 
  plot_4

animate(plot_4, duration=5, fps=2, renderer=gifski_renderer())
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `shadow_*`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(transformr)

main_data <-
  data.frame(
    timestep = as.POSIXct(1L:10L, origin = Sys.time()),
    x = 1L:10L,
    y = 1L:10L
  )

plot_1 <- main_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  transition_time(timestep) + 
  shadow_wake(wake_length = 10)

animate(plot_1, duration = 5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

or:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(transformr)

main_data <-
  data.frame(
    timestep = as.POSIXct(1L:10L, origin = Sys.time()),
    x = 1L:10L,
    y = 1L:10L
  )

plot_1 <- main_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  transition_time(timestep) + 
  shadow_mark(future = TRUE)

animate(plot_1, duration = 5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The geom_path layer should be plotted and remain plotted throughout, the shadow doesn't work for me partly because I need to plot multiple points.